# Radionbutton init with no option selected

Tags: python, tkinter, radio-button

I am making a program in python 3 and I need to put 2 radionbutton. However, I would like that when the program starts, both are blank, with no option selected. Are there any commands that leave them disabled until there is a click of the mouse cursor? I wish the boxes were blank when starting the program

[image]

Comment: From a usability perspective, that's poor design. If you don't want either of them selected, I recommend you have a third option which is "no choice" or "neither" or "none of the above" or whatever language makes sense. Have you tried simply setting the associated variable to a value other than the two supported values?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a simple solution for you:

```
import tkinter as tk

root = tk.Tk()

y_n = tk.StringVar()
y_n.set('None Selected')

r1 = tk.Radiobutton(root, text='NADH', variable=y_n, value='Y').pack()
r2 = tk.Radiobutton(root, text='FAD', variable=y_n, value='N').pack()

root.mainloop()
```

You have to set the value of the `y_n` variable to something that is not the value of any of the `Radiobutton`s. Just like I have set it to `None Selected`, You have to set it to something other than `'Y'`, `'N'`, or `''(Empty String)`.

Comment: @MatheusPena Please make sure to accept the answer if it solves your issue. :)